# Google Nearby Places Android - Need to apply Restrictions

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I wanted to show nearby places in my android app which as per my understanding is only supported by [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) and not by [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/current-place). I went ahead with Google Places API option and have added the same in my android app. I want to restrict API usage to only API calls coming via Android app. However since it goes as a plain GET request via mobile app, i am unable to restrict it with Android App option in my Google API restrictions by providing SHA-1 and namespace of android app. What is the other way out?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Places API web service. Typically Google Maps APIs web services are supposed to be called from backend servers and they support only IP address restrictions.

You can read about restrictions that can be set for different APIs at

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#keysystem

As you can see Places API web service can use only IP address restriction. As you are sending requests directly from mobile devices it doesn't make much sense. Each device has its own IP address and you don't know IP addresses of devices. So the only feasible workaround in order to protect API key is creation of the intermediate backend server.

The app should send request to your intermediate server with corresponding authentication, your intermediate backend server should send request to Google with protected API key restricted to IP address of your server and proxy results back to your app.

In this scenario you need two API keys. One for Google Maps Android SDK with Android app restriction and another one for Places API web service with IP address restriction.

I hope this helps!